# Classifier allways predicts the same label

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I'm training diferent classifieres lik Desciscion Trees or SVC and they allways predict the same label.
The label that predict it's the most frequent label in the dataset.The report is somthing like this:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1       0.46      1.00      0.63       263
      2       0.00      0.00      0.00       163
      3       0.00      0.00      0.00       144
```

avg / total       0.46      1.00      0.63       570

There is any way to avoid the classifier to predict the most ferquent class?

Comment: Look into the class_weight parameter and also try tuning the other parameters.

Comment: What version are you running? I've seen a similar bug before (reported here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4879 )

Comment: @mbatchkarov it's 0.16.1

Comment: @andreas.muller i tried but it's very tricky to take all the clases,there is any tip/trick to balance it?

Answer (score 0):

SVC constructor has a parameter *weight* that can be set to 'auto'. This makes weights proportional to the label frequency.